# URL parsing issue in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am new to Python programming. While making an application, I ran into this problem.

I am parsing URL using **urllib** library of python. I want to convert any relative url into its corresponding absolute url. I get relative and absolute URLs in random fashiion and they may not be from the same domain. Now how do I store the last known absolute url to extract the **netloc** from it and append it to relative url? Should I save the last known absolute URL in a text file? Or is there any better option to this problem?

Comment: Where are you getting the urls from? If you're getting them from the web, then you must have the absolute url at hand, no?

Comment: yes, i am getting the urls from web but i am also trying to extract urls from the available url...this gives me both the absolute as well as the relative url.

Comment: I sitll don't understand your problem. Can't you do something like `for a in BeautifulSoup(urlopen(base_url)).find_all('a'): url= urllib.basejoin(base_url, a['href'])`?

Answer (score 0):

> Now how do I store the last known absolute url to extract the netloc
>   from it and append it to relative url? Should I save the last known
>   absolute URL in a text file?

What do you think is wrong with this? Seems to make sense to me... (depending on context, obviously)